# Scrape Two Elements

Tags: php

I am trying to scrape two different things from a page, if i only scrape the links then i can do a foreach and get the links but i also want the title that is representing that link as well.

Here is an example of the markup of the page

```
<div id="parent">
<span id="title">Title</span>


<div id="Two">
<a href="somelink">Somelink</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the example of just getting the titles and links

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=Two] a') as $a){
echo $a->href;
}

foreach($html->find('span[id=title]') as $az){
echo $az->plaintext;
}
```

But i need them in one loop so i can have the title and its respective link

Something like

```
foreach($html->find('span['id=title'] as $a, div[id=Two] a') as $aa){
```

Though that wont work

Im using simple html dom

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work provided that there is ALWAYS both a title and a link:

```
$links = $html->find('div[id=Two] a');
$titles = $html->find('span[id=title]');

foreach ($links as $i => $a)
{
    echo $titles[$i]->plaintext;
    echo $a->href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested at all but something like this should work. You may need to add validation checks to ensure each title has a link.

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=parent]') as $parent) {
    $title = $parent->find('span[id=title]')->plaintext;
    $href = $parent->find('div[id=Two] a')->href;

    echo $title . ': ' . $href . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: In that case it's not finding any `div[id=parent]`s - are they definitely ID'ed?